# Find a sequence in $L^1$ that satisfies the given properties

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}\in L^1([0,1])$ satisfying the following three properties:

(i) $f_n(x)\to 0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$;

(ii) $\int_{[0,1]}f_nd\mu\le 2013$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$;

(ii) $\{f_n\}$ does not converge in $L^1([0,1])$?

Justify your answer.

I am stuck to create an example that satisfies all the properties. For example $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ does not satisfy all the properties.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: tall, thin rectangles with constant area.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/721563)

Comment: I consider it better to provide hints rather than full answers for homework questions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Thank you very much for your hints I am now working on finding such example.

Comment: Interesting. Five users have recommended this to be deleted, one did vote that way, but no downvotes. Go figure?

Comment: @RobertIsrael So far I got $f_n(x)=n,\,\,0\le x<\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ otherwise, but it does not satisfy the fist property. Need some extra help. Thank you very much

Comment: You're almost there.  Just change $0\le x$ to $0 < x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I am confused with the fact that even if $0<x$ then $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $0$, Am I wrong?

Comment: Since $f_n(x) = 0$ for $n > 1/x$, it does converge to $0$.